# VS 11 -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS in Vs 10 treated as errors now

Tags: visual-studio, boost

I was trying to use latest boost ::split function and with older VS compiler you usually got a warning when using it related to unsafe operations in implementation of the boost code.

Now when using Vs 11 it throws you an error regarding that. Is there a way to make it compile without modifying boost code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more testing we saw that using -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS on command line works. It does not show errors anymore.