# Warning with boost::split when compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does calling boost:split() give so many warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653155/why-does-calling-boostsplit-give-so-many-warnings)

So, this is my code:

```
Account ParseString(string data){
    vector <string> fields;
    boost::split( fields, data, boost::is_any_of( "a,;" ));
    int limit = fields.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        cout << fields[i] << endl;
}
```

and this is what I get when trying to compile:

```
d:\program files (x86)\visualstudio\vc\include\xutility(2227): warning C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
```

My question is, what have I done wrong? What can I do to prevent those error messages?

Comment: It's okay to disable that warning.

Comment: [This warning is an error in MSVC2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618087/vs-11-d-scl-secure-no-warnings-in-vs-10-treated-as-errors-now).

Comment: This warning is an error in MSVS2017

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You haven't done anything wrong.  Visual Studio is being overly cautious.  In debug mode, visual studio uses something called "Checked Iterators".  Pointers are also iterators, but the checking mechanism doesn't work with them.  So when a standard library algorithm is called with pointers, which is something that `boost::split` does, it issues this warning.

You'll get the same warning with this obviously safe code:

```
int main()
{
    int x[10] = {};
    int y[10] = {};
    int *a = x, *b = y;
    std::copy(a, a+10, b);
}
```

Disable the warning.  It's for beginners.  It's on by default for the safety of beginners, because if it was off by default, they wouldn't know how to turn it on.

Comment: Thanks, and where can i turn it off? :)

Comment: @Theolodis: Add `-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to the command line.  In the IDE, you can go to "Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line" and add it in the additional options field.

Answer (score 1):

You have done nothing wrong and if you have a look at the warning it does not seem that scary :) Also I believe in this case you are not required to perform any action on that one.